# How to change URL of createObjectURL method

Tags: angular, typescript, url

I am getting a blob which is a pdf file and opening it in a new window but i am using **createObjectURL** method which create a random generated URL. I want to change it to a Customized URL if that possible
here is my Function that generates it.

```
ExportReport(transaction: any) {
    const urlValue = this.url + "/ExportReport";
    if(transaction.isReprintReport){
      this.coreSession.ModalLoading.Show();
    }
    this.http.post(urlValue, transaction, { responseType: "blob" }).map(res => {
      var blob = new Blob([res], { type: "application/pdf" });
      return blob;
    }).subscribe(
      success => {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(success);
        window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
        if(transaction.isReprintReport){
          this.coreSession.ModalLoading.Hide();
        }
      },
      err => {
        if (transaction.isReprintReport) {
          this.coreSession.ModalLoading.Hide();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

it generates the URL like this :  `blob:http://localhost:55807/9b55903b-79ea-4435-9086-124ce457443a` but i want is something like this  `blob:http://localhost:TransactionID`